# How can check multidomain for magento site on 127.0.0.1 server?

Tags: php, magento, xampp, magento-1.9

I refer Magento Multistore Tutorial from http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/multistore but in document only testing for sub domain and sub directory **how can test multi domain on local server(127.0.0.1)?**

Comment: Not really familiar with magento, but have you tried `php -S localhost:8000` and then going to http://localhost:8000 on the computer you are testing on?

Answer (score 1):

For using multiple or different domains for each website,

- instead of sub domain in base url , use your domain name ..
- then you need to add a virtual host entry pointing to your magento directory
  http://inspiredm.com/enhanced-guide-setting-multi-site-multi-domain-using-magento/
- if this is only testing in your local then you should also add an
  entry in hosts file in your local pc for that domain name ..
  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/